# Permission error trying to bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I try to bundle install on any of my rails projects it provides me with that error. The strange thing is that this file is inexistent and even if I create it and chmod it to writeable it still fails with the same error. How can I solve this?
The error is following: 
*There was an error while trying to write to
/tmp/bundler-compact-index-20170516-7063-bzwspt/versions. It is likely that
you need to grant write permissions for that path.*

### Environment

```
Bundler   1.14.5
Rubygems  2.6.10
Ruby      2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 0) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Git       2.9.3
Platform  x86_64-linux
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```
ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta3', '< 5.1'
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem 'rake', '< 11.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '< 5.x'

gem 'dotenv'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'dotenv-deployment', require: 'dotenv/deployment'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.9'
gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', submodules: true
gem 'country_select'
gem 'paranoia', github: 'radar/paranoia', branch: 'core'

gem 'chartjs-ror', '~> 2.2.0'

gem 'wfarr-ciunas', '~> 0.0.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # deploy
  gem 'capistrano', '3.4.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'active-record-query-trace'
end

gem 'gritter'

gem 'rubocop'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', ref: '88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'cloudinary', '1.1.2'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'sproutvideo-rb'

gem 'bootbox-rails', '~>0.4'
gem 'kaminari', git: 'git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'ckeditor', '4.2.0'

gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'mailgun_rails'
end

gem 'sitemap'
gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'mini_magick'

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.14.4
```

[image: this is what I get when I try to bundle install]

Comment: Can you post the Gemfile content?

Comment: Can you please show us the output (by editing your original post, not in the comments) of running `bundle env`? It is also highly preferable for users to copy+paste text into question, rather than taking a screenshot of it.

Comment: 1) This is just a wild guess, but perhaps bundler is copying something from `~/.bundle/cache/*` into `/tmp`, and the permission error is therefore somewhere in  the `~/.bundle` hierarchy, and not in `/tmp`. I would check everything in `~/.bundle` to make sure. 2) Is there enough space on `/tmp`?

Comment: Hmm... what *are* the permissions on `/tmp`? (And `~/.bundle`?) Have you done anything 'unusual' to them? Are you running in a strange environment, e.g. inside a docker container?

Comment: No, just an rvm environment. No Docker or something.

Comment: Check your bundler version. If it's different than the one specified in `Gemfile.lock`, it could be trying to update that `BUNDLED WITH` line.